# Enable large pages in Windows programmatically

Tags: c, winapi

I want to use large pages in my app like this:

```
VirtualAlloc(NULL, n_bytes, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT | MEM_LARGE_PAGES, PAGE_READWRITE, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

I plan to enable large pages for the *current user* during installation, *while having elevated admin rights*. Does anyone have code for enabling large pages programmatically?

Comment: you forget `MEM_COMMIT` flag. call `VirtualAlloc(NULL, n_bytes, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_LARGE_PAGES, PAGE_READWRITE);` in what problem ?

Comment: @RbMm Fixed. Anyway, before calling it I have to obtain `SeLockMemoryPrivilege` privelege for the user account https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yes, need. are problem get  `SeLockMemoryPrivilege` ?

Comment: and not `user account` but calling thread must have this privilege enabled. or process if thread not impersonate.

Comment: @RbMm It is possible to have it for a whole user account, too. At least it's possible via Group Policy Management Console, and MSDN implies something like that _"For more information, see Assigning Privileges to an Account"_

Comment: look like you not understand. `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` looking for thread token if it exist. if not exist get process token. and looking are `SE_LOCK_MEMORY_PRIVILEGE` exist in token with `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` attribute. all. about account - what is privilege will be exist and enable it default token for new process in logon session. but even if privilege enabled for account (say admin account) - under UAC process can have restricted token

Comment: 1) Read Raymond Chen's article [Some remarks on VirtualAlloc and MEM_LARGE_PAGES](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110128-00/?p=11643). 2) Look at [IGroupPolicyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374235.aspx) and  3) the general [API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374176.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting what I've gathered.

The general idea:

1. Enable large pages for the current user account. (Requires admin rights).
2. Enable large pages for the current process token. (Requires admin rights).
3. Allocate the memory (granular to large page size, 2Mb, in fact).

If you have UAC [properly disabled](https://superuser.com/a/1013725/203579), you need to execute *step 1* only once with admin rights. If you have UAC enabled, you always have to execute it all with admin rights.

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <ntsecapi.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <Sddl.h>

void InitLsaString(PLSA_UNICODE_STRING LsaString, LPWSTR String)
{
    DWORD StringLength;

    if (String == NULL) {
        LsaString->Buffer = NULL;
        LsaString->Length = 0;
        LsaString->MaximumLength = 0;
        return;
    }

    StringLength = wcslen(String);
    LsaString->Buffer = String;
    LsaString->Length = (USHORT)StringLength * sizeof(WCHAR);
    LsaString->MaximumLength = (USHORT)(StringLength + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
}

NTSTATUS OpenPolicy(LPWSTR ServerName, DWORD DesiredAccess, PLSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle)
{
    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING ServerString;
    PLSA_UNICODE_STRING Server = NULL;

    // 
    // Always initialize the object attributes to all zeroes.
    // 
    ZeroMemory(&ObjectAttributes, sizeof(ObjectAttributes));

    if (ServerName != NULL) {
        // 
        // Make a LSA_UNICODE_STRING out of the LPWSTR passed in
        // 
        InitLsaString(&ServerString, ServerName);
        Server = &ServerString;
    }

    // 
    // Attempt to open the policy.
    // 
    return LsaOpenPolicy(
        Server,
        &ObjectAttributes,
        DesiredAccess,
        PolicyHandle
    );
}

NTSTATUS SetPrivilegeOnAccount(LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle, PSID AccountSid, LPWSTR PrivilegeName, BOOL bEnable)
{
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING PrivilegeString;

    // 
    // Create a LSA_UNICODE_STRING for the privilege name.
    // 
    InitLsaString(&PrivilegeString, PrivilegeName);

    // 
    // grant or revoke the privilege, accordingly
    // 
    if (bEnable) {
        return LsaAddAccountRights(
            PolicyHandle,       // open policy handle
            AccountSid,         // target SID
            &PrivilegeString,   // privileges
            1                   // privilege count
        );
    }
    else {
        return LsaRemoveAccountRights(
            PolicyHandle,       // open policy handle
            AccountSid,         // target SID
            FALSE,              // do not disable all rights
            &PrivilegeString,   // privileges
            1                   // privilege count
        );
    }
}

void main()
{
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "OpenProcessToken failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;

    // Probe the buffer size reqired for PTOKEN_USER structure
    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, NULL, 0, &dwBufferSize) &&
        (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "GetTokenInformation failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", GetLastError());

        // Cleanup
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        hToken = NULL;

        return -1;
    }

    PTOKEN_USER pTokenUser = (PTOKEN_USER) malloc(dwBufferSize);

    // Retrieve the token information in a TOKEN_USER structure
    if (!GetTokenInformation(
        hToken,
        TokenUser,
        pTokenUser,
        dwBufferSize,
        &dwBufferSize))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "GetTokenInformation failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", GetLastError());

        // Cleanup
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        hToken = NULL;

        return -1;
    }

    // Print SID string
    LPWSTR strsid;
    ConvertSidToStringSid(pTokenUser->User.Sid, &strsid);
    applog(LOG_INFO, "User SID: %S\n", strsid);

    // Cleanup
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    hToken = NULL;

    NTSTATUS status;
    LSA_HANDLE policyHandle;

    if (status = OpenPolicy(NULL, POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT | POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES, &policyHandle))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "OpenPolicy %d", status);
    }

    // Add new privelege to the account
    if (status = SetPrivilegeOnAccount(policyHandle, pTokenUser->User.Sid, SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME, TRUE))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "OpenPSetPrivilegeOnAccountolicy %d", status);
    }

    // Enable this priveledge for the current process
    hToken = NULL;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "OpenProcessToken #2 failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "LookupPrivilegeValue failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    BOOL result = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();

    if (!result || (error != ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "AdjustTokenPrivileges failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", error);
        return -1;
    }

    // Cleanup
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    hToken = NULL;

    SIZE_T pageSize = GetLargePageMinimum();

    // Finally allocate the memory
    char *largeBuffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, pageSize * N_PAGES_TO_ALLOC, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT | MEM_LARGE_PAGES, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (largeBuffer)
    {
        applog(LOG_INFO, "VirtualAlloc failed, error 0x%x", GetLastError());
    }
}
```